# How to send a email with Excel sheet through marco to multiple receivers with small modifications

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have a excel sheet with a sale offer for multiple receivers each day. 
The file has two tabs, Now I created a macro, to send the emails automatic.

The macro has a sub for each day. 
Now one of the tabs is copied to a new worksheet than it changes one cell which has the name of the receiver in it.
After that, it sends the mail through outlook.

The sub begins with:

```
    ' Copy tab to a new worksheet

Sheets("Offer").Select
Sheets("Offer").Copy
    Cells.Select


    ' Copy worksheet with only results to replace formulas

Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


    ' Change the color for cell A15:C15

Range("A15:C15").Select

With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 14336204
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With


    'Format the numbers to 2 numbers after the comma
Range("D20:D47").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"


    ' Turn alerts off

Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    ' Set the author

ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author") = "Author name"
```

Then for each receiver, I have a block like this:

```
    ' email1

Range("D15:H15").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "name1"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Aanbod\Vrijdag\Filename_receivername1", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    'send mail

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = "receiver1@domain.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "subject here"
    .Body = ""
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

And to end the sub:

```
    ' Turn alerts back on

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Close active window

    ActiveWindow.Close

    ' Go to tab1

    Sheets("tab1").Select
```

Now, this is working, but not really efficient. Also for some reason, it's not working entirely on one of the computers we use it on.
On that computer, it skips some of the receivers, so it doesn't send all emails.

Now I like to create an 3rd tab in the sales offer worksheet, with the email addresses in it, including the names of the receivers.

How can I do this?

Comment: do the same users get skipped each time? Do they have any characters in their names that prevents the workbook from getting saved? Please share some examples of users for which files could not be created.

Answer (score 0):

So I rebuild the code now, so it uses a loop for generating the files and sending the mails.

This is what I got now:
    Sub Maakbestanden_maandag()

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Kopers-Maandag")

Dim Ab As Worksheet
Set Ab = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Aanbod")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("Aanbod").Select
Sheets("Aanbod").Copy
    Cells.Select

Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Range("A15:C15").Select

With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 14336204
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

Range("D20:D49").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

Range("C20:C49").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

Range("E20:F49").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 8
Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 6

ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author") = "AUTHOR NAME"

Range("G50").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-30]C:R[-1]C)"

Range("G51").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C/12"

Dim i As Integer
Dim last_row As Long

last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sh.Range("A:A"))

For i = 2 To last_row

Range("D15:H15").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Sh.Range("B" & i).Value

Range("D15:H15").Select

Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Sh.Range("C" & i).Value, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWindow.Close

MsgBox "Bestanden aangemaakt"

Call Verstuuremail_maandag
```

End Sub

and than to send the actual mails:

```
Sub Verstuuremail_maandag()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Kopers-Maandag")

Dim OA As Object
Dim msg As Object

Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim i As Integer
Dim last_row As Long

last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sh.Range("A:A"))

For i = 2 To last_row
Set msg = OA.createitem(0)

msg.To = Sh.Range("A" & i).Value
msg.Subject = "Sales offer"

msg.body = ""

If Sh.Range("C" & i).Value <> "" Then
msg.attachments.Add Sh.Range("C" & i).Value
End If

DoEvents
msg.send

Next i

MsgBox "E-mails voor maandag verstuurd"

Sheets("Veilprijzen").Select

End Sub
```

Now when I'm testing it, it works well, but still sometimes it stops at 2/3 of the way while sending the mails (generating the files works fully everytime).

When it stops, it's trowing the following error:
vba error 5 invalid procedure call or argument

VBA marks it at: msg.send

It's odd, sometimes we get a full run on the same day, with the very same code and customer information, and sometimes it doesn't go all the way.

Any recommendation to solve this?